# Why tilting a radio makes it play?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, interference, home-experiment, radio

I was helping my mother in making her radio play.

There was no technical issues with the radio, but it would go crazy when a nearby tubelight was switched on.

We tried many things, adjusted the antenna, tried a different FM and what not.

Until finally, an accidental tilt given to the radio during our operations, made it silent!

[image: Tilt radio]

It stopped all the noise and played perfectly.

How did *tilting*, simply *tilting*, do the job?

Comment: Maybe a bad contact inside the radio that was fixed by tilting it?

Comment: Possibly polarisation of the interference is a factor here?

Comment: A familiar phenomenon but I have not experienced it for quite a while.  Maybe I have been lucky or newer radios are better.  Analogue TVs with internal aerials were particularly prone.  I also guessed that it was due to polarisation.

Comment: I told you it's nothing to do with technical errors. I did the tilting to and fro, and the noise comes and goes and so on. This shows that it's nothing technical. I suspect some property of electromagnetic interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electromagnetism is not a compression wave. Its a transverse wave. That means the coupling of an antenna to that energy depends on the orientation of the antenna. Its like if you hold a tube horizontally on the surface of water. The water waves will cause an alternating flow through the tube only when the tube is oriented perpendicular to the wave motion.

Comment: If it were so, wouldn't you hear noises if you turn your car with its FM on?

Comment: Typically, mobile antennas are designed to accept signals from as many directions as possible, and also the transmit power is typically strong enough to be picked up even when the antenna orientation is not optimal. But strong electromagnetism from a nearby source can enter the radio at different parts of the circuit, and different frequencies. I suspect the fluorescent light was interfering in the baseband (audio). Probably along a speaker or internal power wire. And possibly by near-field energy.